# Looking for a verb meaning "make something unnecessary"

Tags: word-request

X [verb here] Y meaning: Doing X is sufficient and so Y is not needed.

> Does listening make speaking unnecessary?
>
> Does listening [verb here] speaking?

Comment: Such a verb would be **obviate** (one of whose meanings is 'to render unnecessary') but it is  not a better choice, in your examples, for "make...unnecessary".

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=JE2xDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT101&dq=%22obviates+having%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlla-bvIrSAhUTfiYKHR8cDoUQ6AEIhQEwEg#v=onepage&q=%22obviates%20having%22&f=false

Comment: @Rose When "make" is used in that pattern (please see this other thread I took part in recently: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/102932/make-it-clear-what/119143#119143), "render" seems to me to be a better word.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest **invalidate** or its synonyms:

- nullify
- negate
- make ineffective
- neutralize
- cancel
- undo
- annul
- void

Comment: Depending on your context, "Does listening make speaking unnecessary?" is actually a pretty good sentence. It could be the better choice in something like: "Does listening make speaking unnecessary? No, but a good listener is usually sparse with his words."